# Android - Treat external storage as internal storage?

Tags: storage

I bought a Blu Dash smartphone at frys. It's a nifty little 40$ phone. The biggest problem is that it only comes with - I shit you not - 100 mb of internal space. I can decide to install apps on sdcard and choose it as default write location, but it still installs some data on internal storage, and gives me the "insufficient space" error when installing apps.

So my question is, can I trick my device into thinking my 7gb sdcard is the internal storage so I can install apps?

Edit: Forgot to mention I'm rooted and know my way around ADB and the like, so feel free to suggest some long convoluted process.

Comment: Off-topic. Please read the android tag.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly... only Marshmallow can adopt external storage as internal, but assuming this is the Blu Dash 5.0, you can [root](https://theunlockr.com/2014/08/14/how-to-root-the-blu-dash-5-0/) it, and use an app like [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en) or [App2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en) to move apps to the SD card. You way want to consider a larger SD card though, since you have to partition the card and will lose some normal storage space.

The real problem is that you only have 100mb of internal space available, to use these apps you need to install them normally on internal storage, then move them to the SD card. With so little space to work with there may be several apps which cannot be installed so they can be moved.

This is the problem with buying a phone with only 4GB of space, although the price seems right if it is almost unusable for anything besides a basic phone, it may not be the right phone for you. I would suggest getting a phone with a minimum of 8GB of storage and 1GB of RAM.

Comment: I'm rooted and have seen apps like [external2internal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dI7ocngfhEk) but I'm not sure how to use them. I've followed videos like the one there, but to no results at all. I have download link2sd but it is looking for a partition that my sdcard doesn't have and I don't exactly know how to partition my sdcard.

Comment: @Beck I am not familiar with that app, but if it was so easy everyone would be doing it... Not that I know everything, but I have rarely heard of anyone able to make this (using SD card as internal) work on any device. I would suggest staying within well documented and supported apps like the ones I mentioned above.